# Are there any Starbucks locations open after 11pm in the West Village?

Tags: new-york-city, food-and-drink

I did a search online but couldn't find an accurate list.  Anybody know of a list by neighbourhood that is up-to-date?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something not related to travel.

Comment: @Doc: well, I'm travelling in NYC and I want to know the hours they keep here...I don't see how this is any different from people asking what  time etc. they should board a train etc....and I'm trying to plan a schedule around authentic opening hours for all types of establishments.

Comment: The ones open late tend to be farther uptown, e.g. in Penn Station, and there's a 24 hour one off Times Square.

Comment: Man, people must be really desperate for a latte to put a bounty on this.

Comment: @zeocrash Hey, no other store has been able to beat the deliciousness of the Frappucino! None. 

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Starbucks official website](http://www.starbucks.com/store-locator/search/location/west%20village%2C%20new%20york%2C%20ny%2C%20united%20states), there are two Starbucks locations close to West Village that fulfill your requirements

1. > Lafayette & 8th Street
   >
   > **13-25 Astor Place**
   >
   > ```
   > Open  5:30 AM to 1:00 AM
   > ```
2. > New York University
   >
   > **45 West 4th Street**
   >
   > ```
   > Open 7:00 AM to 12:00 AM
   > ```

Comment: Websites are often not updated. Does anyone who knows if that's really their hours?

Comment: @verve Starbucks is one of the world's largest corporations. If anyone keeps their website updated, it's them.

Answer (score 1):

[Starbucks store allocater](http://www.starbucks.com/store-locator/search/location) may help you.

It can show every single Starbucks location, opening time, plus some extra service like wifi/mbile payment/24-hours opening,  on **Earth**.

However, many Starbucks stops selling around half hour before closed.

Comment: So what's the answer to his question, according to the site? Remember, links are good, but answers are better.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's one, according to [Yelp](http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=starbucks&find_loc=West%20Village%2C%20Manhattan%2C%20NY&ns=1&ls=9a9eb218a8e0db7b#open_time=1395).

Comment: Set the filter to "11:29" and you get a few results that close at 11:30 that are in fact in the West Village, and even better, on Fri/Sat, are open even later.

Comment: Except the Starbucks website (which would have been the easiest place for the person asking the original question to actually look) disagrees with those times.